# Laravrl5- user permissions for whole module controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5, permissions, middleware

I created a simple system to set permissions for users in the admin panel using AdminMiddleware.
Every user has permissions like groups, posts, pages ....

Routes/web:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/admin' , 'admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin');
  //all admin panel routes
}
```

In the AdminMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){

        if ($request->user()->user_type !== 'man')
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        $user_permissions = Auth::user()->permissions;
        foreach($user_permissions as $value){
            $controller = Controllers::get_controller($value->controller_id);
            $permissions['name'] = $controller->controller_name;

            $all_permissions[] = $permissions;
            unset($permissions);
        }
        foreach ($all_permissions as $value){
            $controllers[] =  trim($value['name']);
        }
        $request->user()->controllers = $controllers;

        return $next($request);

    }
    else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

So I get a list of all user permissions which represent controllers names and in every controller (in this controller i check if the user has permission named 'users' to access the users controller to view their data)

```
protected $user;

public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user= Auth::user();
        if(!in_array('users',$this->user->controllers)){
            session()->flash('error' , 'No permission');
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
        else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    });
}
```

I use this for every controller and it works for a small project but when it comes to a large project with modules ([nWidart/laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules)) it'll be hard. What I want is to check for the permission for the whole module not for every single controller in the module. So if I have a module named blog I want to check if the logged in user has permission to access any controller in that module how could this be done?

Comment: Add your module routes in a route group and add middleware for that route group. That's what laravel does with its own routes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a middleware for every module and in the middleware i get user permissions and check if he the permission to access this group

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){

        if ($request->user()->user_type !== 'man')
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        $user_permissions = Auth::user()->permissions;
        $user_group = Auth::user()->group_id;

        if($user_group == 1){ //all permissions admin
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            //get user permissions as an array

            if(in_array('groups',$user_permissions)){ //module name is groups
                return $next($request);
            }

            else{
                return redirect('/home');
            }
        }


    }
    else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/admin' , 'admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'users'], function()
{
    Route::get('/adminUsers' , '\Modules\Users\Http\Controllers\UsersController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'groups'], function()
{
    Route::get('/groups' , '\Modules\Groups\Http\Controllers\GroupsController@index');
});
```